# "self.interfaceOrientation" not getting updated in iOS 5 

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

i have recently updated to my iPad to iOS5 and found a rather strange problem. I have 2 different layouts for both orientations in my App. I am updating the views in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method by taking reference from `self.interfaceOrientation`. But now the `self.interfaceOrientation` is not getting updated and the views are showing up weirdly. Can anyone throw some light on this issue. Is there some thing new with iOS 5 which is giving me this trouble ???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any changes in iOS 5, but here's the code I've used since iOS 4 and worked fine ever since.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation){

       case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
       case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

       //change layout to Portrait 

       return YES;

       case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
       case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:

       //change layout to Landscape 

        return YES;

        default:
            return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: I am offering an alternative way to implement his layout when the orientation changes. This alternative way solves the bug described in the question.

Comment: Ah, I see; you're suggesting that the layout changes be inserted where your comments are. I had misunderstood. This is still a bad idea, though; `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` can be called without an impending rotation; if you put your controller in a navigation controller, it will call this method 4 times in quick succession and cache the return values.

Comment: I think he might have used `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` by accident, which wouldn't work - [see Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIInterfaceOrientation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

and set orientation to variable, but it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the way you actually grabbing the device orientation. In my experience `self.interfaceOrientation` isn't always reliable.

There are several ways to get the current `UIInterfaceOrientation`, but from my understanding getting the orientation from the status bar is the only relatively effective method so try using that instead:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

**Reminder** - `UIInterfaceOrientation` and `UIDeviceOrientation` are not the same! They may also update at different times depending on how you initialize them.

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738815/740474) on a similar question.