# Device orientation sometimes returns an unknown value when rotating too fast

Tags: cocoa-touch, uideviceorientation

I am implementing iAd on iPad, and since I'm creating everything programmatically, I need to manually move the frame of the ad every time the user rotates the screen.

I uses the notification center to detect when the user rotates the device.

The problem is, sometimes when I rotate the device too fast the orientation becomes "UIDeviceOrientationUnknown". In this case, how can I tell the screen orientation to adjust the ad position accordingly?

I do not wish to use auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

I normally ask the status bar for orientation, 'cause it's always either landscape or portrait, like so: 
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`. In any case, there are a few approaches. I recommend reading through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738734/get-current-orientation-of-ipad).

Comment: Hmm, seems status bar orientation also got 5 orientations, because I used `NSLog(%@"%i", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);` and it gave me either 1, 2,  3, 4 or UNKNOWN.