# Forcing Portrait Mode in a UIPageViewController on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an iPad app which supports Portrait and Landscape in the entire app. This is an iOS 7 and iOS 8 version of an app.

The app is a `UITableViewController` with multiple segues to a different set of `UIViewControllers`. I have one option in the app to show the Tutorial again and I have created the images in a Portrait mode only orientation because it just wouldn't make too much sense (or look good in Landscape).

With this in mind, the tutorial is in the form of images loaded into a `UIPageViewController`. The images are loaded in the `viewDidLoad` and the buttons and layout work really well.

**Issue**
I want to restrict the `UIPageViewController` to be in a Portrait orientation only.

Currently, I have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];

}
```

That works to some extent. If the device is in Landscape mode and the tutorial is invoked, it rotates it to Portrait.

**However, if the device is in Portrait and I rotate it to Landscape after invoking the Tutorial, the tutorial then rotates.**

How exactly do I prevent this view from rotating in my custom `UIPageViewController` class, so that it never rotates to Landscape whether it's at the start, middle, or end of the tutorial.

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at UIViewController docs for Orientation support, specifically `shouldAutorotate:` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations

My first guess would be you would want to set the value like you're doing now, and then override `shouldAutorotate` in your custom UIPageViewController subclass and return NO.

However, be aware you could get hit in the review process for HIG compliance, because your app claims to support all orientations, but parts of it don't. Obviously this is totally up to the reviewer and whether or not they catch it as plenty of other apps do this.

Comment: Thanks so much Matt - that is really helpful and a very good thinking about the possible rejection. With shouldAutorotate set to no, it works with my app starting in Portrait mode, however if the tutorial starts in Landscape, it doesn't rotate to Portrait (understandably). 

So thinking about making a Landscape tutorial, can I easily determine which orientation I'm in and show that appropriate image? So load all the images in the viewDidLoad, but then detect the orientation and adjust the images in real time? (Perhaps a different question required if it's more than a simple method?)

Comment: I generally use the statusBarOrientation property off of UIApplication - but per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2738815/490180) there are a few different ways to do it, and none are guaranteed 100% in all situations.

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks so much Matt and your advice about possible rejection is just great. To be honest, even if it doesn't get rejected, it's a cheap way to implement this and ultimately it's a weird UI if you're using the app in Landscape. Come to think of it, I wouldn't be happy with that in an app, so no reason I should employ that too. Thanks again Matt.