# iOS: Detect if iPad is flat (Horizontal to the ground)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, camera, orientation

I've written a program that allows a user to score a scantron test using the iPad's built in camera, and it gets best results when the iPad is held flat in the air looking down on the test. How can I detect that the iPad is being help flat so I can prevent the user from taking a bad picture?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738734/get-current-orientation-of-ipad , it seems very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with UIAccelerometer in the past, but the modern way is to use Core Motion to check the attitude of the device. This article explains Core Motion pretty well. http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/
Basically, if the value for attidude in the z axis is close to 1 or -1 then the iPad is flat (facing down or up).