# UITableView with Custom cell style

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I create a `UITablveVIew` like this?

[image]

Comment: here are some good link to help you.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477277/rotate-a-custom-uitableviewcell and this to rotate as table (i think u need that too) http://www.iphonedeveloperdiary.com/2010/05/supporting-iphone-landscapeportrait-orientations-uitableviewcells/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Custom Cell for this design and use table View Editing Style to add new rows in table.

Check here for sample Projects

[Table View Sample1](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-delete-data-from-tableview-in-iphone/)
[Table View Sample2](http://learn-iphone-app-development.com/2011/01/31/tables-part-iii-%E2%80%94-re-ordering-moving-cells-and-swipe-to-delete/)

Hope this will helps u

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a custom `UITableViewCell`
2. Load all the controls which you need to use. For eg in this case `UIButton`, `UILable` etc etc
3. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you need to put condition depending upon which row you are.
4. Set alpha to 1 for the controls which you need. And put alpha to 0 for the controls which you don't need to display. And, also you can change their attributes for e.g. changing the font of `UILable` or changing the image of `UIButton`

Note : To implement this kind of `UITableView` it is important for you know what will be the format of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You subclass `UITableViewCell`. I've done it myself, and here are some great links on the topic:

[The best way to do custom, reusable UITableViewCells](http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/)

[Custom UITableViewCell with IB](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)

The IB method is very straightforward.